# My application will not display anything? just a blank white page?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-intent

I made an app it was working perfectly I also had a imageview with scrolling pictures.

All I did was add a button and after that when I run it the app will not show anything. just a plain white blank screen. I have a feeling it could be an intent issue but they seem to be fine with no errors.

Like I said the intents were working fine. I've checked every bit of my code but doesn't seem to load up my Main activity layout.(xml)

Unfortunately I didn't keep a backup . Also LogCat Doest not say anything whatsoever

`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Welcome to iStyle Events"
    android:textColor="#FF9500"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Gallery"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF9500"
        android:text="@string/Gallery" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#fafad2"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Services"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:textColor="#FF9500"
    android:text="@string/Services" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Contact"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:textColor="#FF9500"
    android:text="@string/Contact" />
```

`

.java =

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
Button service;
Button gallery;
Button contact;


protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   service = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Services);
   service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {

        Intent intent = new Intent (Main.this, servicesActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
     }

   });
   gallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
   gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent (Main.this, galleryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
        }

    }); 
    contact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Contact);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent (Main.this, contactActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent2);

        }

    });
}
}
```

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.istyleevents"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="1"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.istyleevents.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name="galleryActivity"></activity>
       <activity android:name="servicesActivity"></activity>
       <activity android:name="contactActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your main activity layout XML and any other code you think is relevant? There's not really enough information here to help out.

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply i have added it sorry about that

Comment: Remove the button you added and see if the screen content returns. You may want to consider something easier to work with than RelativeLayout, unless you need its functionality (can't tell unless i see a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1 behind the method onCreate. Is it just a copy-paste mistake ? If I remove it, you layout is shown

Comment: oh my god thank you so much!!!!!it wors again @esteam . can you please explain why this is happening just so i can get a better understanding

Comment: From Android documentation:  onCreate - Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one. Check this link to see more http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on your onCreate method. It's written as onCreate1. If that's how it's written in the java file and not just a copt&paste error here, that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your android:layout_width and android:layout_height and make sure they are not cover other content is my guesss please post the xml file